# Move left and right in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` which scrolls only horizontally. I have a situation where I have views filled by array in `UIScrollView`. There are three views which altogether make one single component in `UIScrollView` (there are many such components). Component contains :

- UILabel
- UIButton
- UIView (for underlying text)

I have placed two arrow keys(left and right) at the ends of `UIScrollView`. On touching left arrow I am shifting one position left (with complete string to display) in `UIScrollView` and one position right (with complete string to display) in case of right arrow button.

Till now I am able to perform left arrow action. But I have no idea how to perform right arrow touch and how to display complete string to touching arrow keys if only part of that string is being displayed.

I know it is weird that I have a `UIScrollView` and still want to add arrow keys to move it. But can't help it. This is client's requirement. The following is how I implemented left arrow action:

```
-(IBAction) onClickLeftArrow
{
    NSLog(@"BUTTON VALUE : %i",iButtonValue);
    if(iButtonValue <= [m_BCListArray count]) {
        NSArray *arr = [scrollDemo subviews];
        for(int j = 0; j < [arr count]; j++) {
            UIView *view1 = [arr objectAtIndex:j];
            [view1 removeFromSuperview];
        }
        XX = 5.0;
        int tagcount = [m_BCListArray count]-iButtonValue;
        NSLog(@"%@",m_BCListArray);
        for(int i = iButtonValue; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            UILabel *blabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(XX, 6, 120, 26)];
            blabel.text = [m_BCListArray objectAtIndex:[m_BCListArray count]-i];
            blabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            blabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            blabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
            [scrollDemo addSubview:blabel];

            //underline code
            CGSize expectedLabelSize = [[m_BCListArray objectAtIndex:[m_BCListArray count]-1] sizeWithFont:blabel.font constrainedToSize:blabel.frame.size lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
            CGRect newFrame = blabel.frame;
            newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
            blabel.frame = CGRectMake(blabel.frame.origin.x, blabel.frame.origin.y, expectedLabelSize.width+10, expectedLabelSize.height);
            blabel.numberOfLines = 1;
            [blabel sizeToFit];
            int width=blabel.bounds.size.width;
            int height=blabel.bounds.size.height;

            UIButton *btnContent = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [btnContent addTarget:self action:@selector(SelectButton:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
            btnContent.tag = tagcount+1;
            btnContent.frame=CGRectMake(XX, 2.0, width+10, height);
            [scrollDemo addSubview:btnContent];
            scrollDemo.contentSize = CGSizeMake(XX+50, 32);
            //scrollDemo.contentSize = CGSizeMake(expectedLabelSize.width,expectedLabelSize.height);

            UIView *viewUnderline=[[UIView alloc] init];
            viewUnderline.frame=CGRectMake(XX, 26, width, 1);
            viewUnderline.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
            [scrollDemo addSubview:viewUnderline];
            [viewUnderline release];

            scrollDemo.contentSize = CGSizeMake(XX+width+10, 32);
            XX = XX + width+10;
            iRight  = iRight + 1;
            tagcount ++;
          //  iRight --;
        }
    }   
    iButtonValue = iButtonValue+1;
}
```

Comment: Please explain more... What do u mean u have to display the string fully ? And wat do u mean by shifting one position left ?  u want the next view to come to the centre indicatin that it s the currently selected one ?

Comment: By full string I mean that complete string should fit in screen(not half hidden). A very long string will be an exception.

Comment: And wat about the position of the string ? should it be centered or somethin like that ?

Comment: U have ur string as a text of UILabel right ?

Comment: Shifting one position left means that on touching left arrow button, previous string(to be displayed on label) will be shown. And if right arrow button is touched, next string to current string will be shown.

Comment: I want to display the first string in the start of scrollview.

Comment: Yes string is to be displayed on uilabel.

Answer (score 1):

Set the contentOffset of UIScrollView on the Button click action and u'll get your desired effect.